# Cannot set Tapping Enabled Default on Archlinux

Tags: archlinux, touchpad, xinput

When I log into Archlinux on Dell Vostro 5590, if I want to "click" something with the touchpad I have to *press* the touchpad, as tapping it is not enough as I'd like it to be.

Running the following

```
xinput set-prop 11 "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

correctly enables that behavior I want. (I got that 11 by examining the output of `xinput list` and that string by examining the output of `xinput list-props 11`.)

However, this setting change does not survive a log-out/reboot.

My understanding is that I should run

```
xinput set-prop 11 "libinput Tapping Enabled Default" 1
```

but this give the following error

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

I know I can put the non-`Default` command in my `~/.xinit` before starting the WM, but I don't think it is a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Libinput - Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/libinput), you must install it first. But mostly it installed by default:

```sh
$ pacman -sS libinput
  extra/libinput 1.18.1-1 [installed] # This is the newer
    Input device management and event handling library
  extra/xf86-input-libinput 1.1.0-1 (xorg-drivers) [installed] # This is older
    Generic input driver for the X.Org server based on libinput
```

Then run `sudo libinput list-devices` to know where is the touchpad's path on kernel:

```sh
$ sudo libinput list-devices
  Device:           SYNA0001:00 06CB:CE2D Touchpad
  Kernel:           /dev/input/event7 # Here is mine
```

Here my config: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`:

```sh
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        Driver "libinput"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event7"
        Option "Tapping" "on"
        Option "ClickMethod" "clickfinger"
        Option "TappingDrag" "on"
        Option "ScrollMethod" "twofinger"
        Option "DisableWhileTyping" "on"
        Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
EndSection
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Create config file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` named **40-libinput.conf** and paste this

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection
```

then after reboot you will have tapping.
Check out [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libinput#Via_Xorg_configuration_file) too.